# Unexpected behavior of window.open, child window isn't mapping from parent page if i change the child window location through window.open

Tags: javascript, window.open, window.opener

here is my code to open url in a new tab

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to open a new browser window.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    window.open("http://www.w3schools.com", 'school');
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

if i keep on clicking the button, every time the child window gets focus (with name school).

Now in child window console i executed the following command

`window.open("http://www.google.com", 'school');`

After I do this if go to parent page and clicked on the button, it's open a new window instead of mapping to the already opened child window (which has window.name as  'school') .

I don't know why

Please help me in fixing this, Thanks in Advance

**update**

- I clicked on a button in a page, it opens a new child window
  (w3schools here with `window.name` as school)
- In the child window (w3schools) browser console i ran this`window.open("http://www.google.com", 'school');`, now child
  window location is http://www.google.com instead of w3schools
- Now again i clicked on the button in **parent** page it opens a new window, but i need focus on the already opened page (which has
  current location as google.com)

Is it possible to achieve ?

Comment: Not certain what Question is? What is expected behaviour?

Comment: Are you trying to change the `location` of the original `window`?

Comment: The origin of the opened `window` is not the same as original `window` at `javascript` at Question. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @guest271314 the child window needs to get focus instead of opening a new window (it's opening a new window as i'm changing the location of child window through window.open) , check [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_open), with the above code

Comment: Are you trying to focus `window.opener` when new `window` opens?

Comment: Still not clear, here,  where you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: You could try `window.opener.focus()` at opened `window`. Though note, the different `windows` do not appear to have the same origin.

Comment: I think window.opener.focus()  will focus the parent window, my requirement is i'm clicking on a button in parent page which should focus the child window after the child window location is changed, just work with my code in w3schools, then you'll get more idea on this

Comment: You have not retained a reference to the opened `window` at `javascript` at Question. Are you  trying to communicate across two to three different origins?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry in the above code i communicated with Cross origins, Thanks **@guest271314**  may be it could be the reason for opening multiple windows.

---

**Unsafe JavaScript attempt to initiate navigation for frame with origin '[CHILD WINDOW URL HERE]' from frame with URL '[PARENT WINDOW URL]'. The frame attempting navigation is neither same-origin with the target, nor is it the target's parent or opener.**

As per the error, I'm communicating with Cross origins when i clicked on the button, to make things work you must have the child window same origin as parent.

let's describe with above example:

```
<p>Click the button to open a new browser window.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    window.open("http://www.w3schools.com", 'school');
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

- I clicked on a button in a page (parent), it opens a new child window
  (w3schools here with `window.name` as school)
- In the child window (w3schools) browser console *previously i ran this `window.open("http://www.google.com", 'school');`, which become a cross origin for parent now,* instead if i redirect to any url that is same origin as parent like below 
  `window.open("http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_examples.asp", 'school');`

  things working fine, if i clicked on the button in **parent** page child window gets focused (previously new windows are opened)

Here i mentioned that I executed some code in Child window browser console, but in my original code I'm doing misc operations in child window using window.open

Hope this helps Someone.